# how to update max replicas in running pod

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-ingress

I'm looking to update manually with the command **kubectl autoscale** my maximum number of replicas for auto scaling.

however each time I run the command it creates a new hpa that fails to launch the pod why I don't know at all:(

Do you have an idea how i can update manually with kubectl my HPA ?

https://gist.github.com/zyriuse75/e75a75dc447eeef9e8530f974b19c28a

Comment: if yout want to scale it manully then why you are using HPA

Answer (score 4):

I think you are mixing two topics here, one is manually scale a pod (you can do it through a deployment applying `kubectl scale deploy {mydeploy} --replicas={#repl}`). In the other hand you have HPA (Horizontal Pod AutoScaler), in order to do this (HPA) you should have configured any app metrics provider system 
e.g:

- metrics server
  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/metrics-server
- heapster (deprecated) https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster

then you can create a HPA to handle your autoscaling, you can get more info on this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/

Once created you can patch your HPA or deleted it and create it again

kubectl delete hpa hpa-pod  -n ns-svc-cas

kubectl autoscale  hpa-pod  --min={#number} --max={#number} -n ns-svc-cas

easiest way

Comment: Okay, I just figured out my mistake between **HPA** and **scale**
HPA: does it automatically but scale it is explicitly asked to do it right away! 
I'm not mistaken?

Comment: this is pretty much the same, summarizing what you are trying to do, is update the HPA definition, in order to change the limit of min and/or max replicas from an existing HPA definition.